# jQuery Modal doesn't show up

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery and the [Reveal Modal jQuery plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) to create modals, base on [this example](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/demo/index.php?p=1379319976).

My PHP code:

```
IF ($q3)
    {
        IF ($admin_default_activate == 0)
        {
            echo "<span style=\"color:green\">Your account is created, but an Administrator must activate it!</span>";
        }
        ELSE
        { echo "

            <div id=\"modal\">
                <div id=\"heading\">
                    Your mailaccount is activated!
                </div>

                <div id=\"boxcontent\">
                    <p><b>Account Details:</b><br><b>Email:</b> $user<br /><b>Password:</b> $userpass1<br><br><b>Settings:</b><br><b>POP3:</b> mail.website.se (Port 110)<br><b>IMAP:</b> mail.website.se (Port 143)<br><b>SMTP:</b> mail.website.se (Port 25/587)</p>

                    <a href=\"#\" class=\"button red close\"><img src=\"popup/images/cross.png\">Close window</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            ";
        }
    }
    ELSE
    {
        //echo "<span style=\"color:red\">Database error: Could not create the account. Contact an Administrator!</span>";
    }
```

The Javascript code is inside the  tag, but it still dont work.

The original button code is:

```
<a href="#" id="button">Click me</a>
```

And the one I use now is:

```
<input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Create">
```

I dont know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Which `div` maybe because `if` condition.

Comment: it's not good to do either, but why are you echoing html, then outputting html via closing php tag? you should stick to one or the other

Comment: I tried to use "echo" too, but that didn´t work either

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I assume you want to have an account to be created on the server upon clicking on the button, and then the user isn't redirected to a new page, but rather the server reply to be displayed in a modal on the same page.

To achieve that, you need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

As for why the modal won't show up:

- make sure both jQuery and reveal.js are loaded
- make you have the jquery code referencing the correct button (or other element) and DIV

As a side-note, like @kennypu noted, you're using both echoed output and closing and opening php tags; you should stick to a pattern.

Comment: Okey. I changed the code back to "echo". But I really do not know how to get the code to be used as AJAX.. :/

Comment: Try reading [tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

Comment: Well, I did, and I tried a couple of other guides but without success for me. I'm not so good at this..